# Android Studio. Application Installation failed

Tags: android

При попытке установить приложение на AVD получил сообщение:

```
Installation failed with message Failed to finalize session: INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: /data/app/vmdl886175740.tmp/5_slice__ signatures are inconsistent.

It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of an apk if it is present, and than re-installing.
```

StackTrace:

```
04-28 15:31:08.031 1563-1601/system_process E/PackageInstaller: Commit of session 886175740 failed: /data/app/vmdl886175740.tmp/5_slice__ signatures are inconsistent
04-28 15:31:08.033 4026-4026/? E/Pm: Failure details: Bundle[{android.content.pm.extra.STATUS=4, android.content.pm.extra.SESSION_ID=886175740, android.content.pm.extra.LEGACY_STATUS=-2, android.content.pm.extra.STATUS_MESSAGE=INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: /data/app/vmdl886175740.tmp/5_slice__ signatures are inconsistent}]
```

После выбора "Удалить существующее приложение" пишет:

```
04-28 15:37:02.849 4314-4314/? E/Pm: Failure details: Bundle[{android.content.pm.extra.STATUS=1, android.content.pm.extra.PACKAGE_NAME=com.xpendence.development.currencyconvarter, android.content.pm.extra.LEGACY_STATUS=-1, android.content.pm.extra.STATUS_MESSAGE=DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR}]
```

Ошибка стала появляться после сборки APK и загрузки значков приложения.

Comment: InstantRun отключите.

Comment: @YuraIvanov ммм... как?

Comment: File-Settings-Build, Execution, Deployment-Instant Run Снять галку.

Comment: Спасибо, всё заработало.

Comment: Включаю заново Instant Run — опять ничего не работает. Как вернуть Instant Run к нормальной работе?

Comment: Никак. Эта функция глючила и глючит всегда и в разных местах. Работает только на презентации гугла.

Comment: @YuraIvanov оформите как ответ - очень полезная инфа

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В общем, как правильно подсказал Юра Иванов, отключайте Instant Run, иначе, намучаетесь с компиляцией.